# I need a sql query loop with dates decrements by a day until break date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a sql query loop with dates decrements by day.

```
StartDate : 3/15/2015    [Date param] [MM/dd/yyyy]
EndDate   : 3/5/2015     [Date param]  
Operation : Decrement by a day toward EndDate
BreakDate : 3/10/2015    [Date param]
```

The current date (in loop) should be printed from start date to end date by a day decrements

IF break date is reached then loop should stop itself [Inside loop]

Sample result above input:

```
3/15/2015 
3/14/2015 
3/13/2015 
3/11/2015 
3/10/2015
```

Please HELP.

Comment: Do you literally mean "print", as in "using the print statement", rather than "be returned as a query result"?  Because printing it would indeed take a loop, but returning it as a query result would require a recursive CTE.

Comment: Use a calendar table. The answer is then incredibly simple: `SELECT the_date FROM dbo.calendar WHERE ...`

Comment: Not sure why you went with the worst answer. Looping is a bad idea. Pick @GarethD's answer. That will make me sleep better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `WHILE` Loop. But before going to loop, consider [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/).

This will give exact output as expected.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '3/15/2015', 
        @EndDate DATE = '3/5/2015',
        @BreakDate DATE = '3/10/2015' 

WHILE (@FromDate >= @endDate)
BEGIN
    PRINT @FromDate

    -- Perform your operations here

    IF(@FromDate = @BreakDate)
        Break;

    --Incrementing to next date
    SELECT @FromDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @FromDate)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a loop. You should **NEVER** approach a problem in SQL with that mindset, it should be a last resort.

If working with dates then the easiest solution would be to use a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html), and if you don't have one create one, then you could just use:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20150315',
        @EndDate DATE = '20150305',
        @BreakDate DATE = '20150310';

SELECT  Date
FROM    Calendar
WHERE   Date <= @StartDate
AND     Date > @EndDate
AND     Date > @BreakDate;
```

However, I appreciate that creating a calendar table is not always an option, but it is very easy to generate a list of dates on the fly. From the following articles:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

The best way to do this on the fly is to use cross joins from constants (referred to as Stacked CTEs in the articles). This just starts with a table valued constructor of 10 rows, cross joins this to itself to get 100 rows, then again to get 100x100 = 10,000 rows, and so on:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20150315',
        @EndDate DATE = '20150305',
        @BreakDate DATE = '20150310';

WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
N4 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - N, @StartDate)
FROM    N4
WHERE   N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @EndDate, @StartDate) + 1
AND     N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @BreakDate, @StartDate) + 1;
```

---

**EDIT**

If your break date can be after the start date then you just need an extra bit of logic to get around that, so your queries become:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20150315',
        @EndDate DATE = '20150305',
        @BreakDate DATE = '20150310';

SELECT  Date
FROM    Calendar
WHERE   Date <= @StartDate
AND     Date > @EndDate
AND (   Date > @BreakDate
    OR  @BreakDate >= @StartDate
    );
```

Or

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20150315',
        @EndDate DATE = '20150305',
        @BreakDate DATE = '20150320';

WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
N4 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - N, @StartDate)
FROM    N4
WHERE   N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @EndDate, @StartDate) + 1
AND (   N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @BreakDate, @StartDate) + 1
    OR  @BreakDate >= @StartDate
    );
```

Comment: You made the same mistake i made at first. Try a breakdate at '20150320', it will exclude all rows

Comment: Easily the best approach posted!

Comment: @t-clausen.dk easy fix: `IF @BreakDate <= @EndDate BEGIN SET @EndDate = @BreakDate END` then remove the final bit of the WHERE clause.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you might have missed my edit: need to remove the part of the WHERE clause that refers to BreakDate. Basically we want the days between the start and whichever comes first out of the End and Break dates. If we work out which one comes first, we use that as our upper limit alone `:-)`

Comment: @gvee no, had not seen your edit, comment removed. However what makes this approach so much better than mine ? It is more or less the same except for the tally table

Comment: I think the improvement is scalability, recursive CTEs are not much better than a while loop - I personally hate to see them used in this way on Stackoverflow, because the poster may know that because it is only for a few 100 rows that the performance impact will be negligible, but in this case the performance impact of a while loop would be negligible too, so that is not an argument. The real problem is the people that read the answer that don't know recursive CTEs do not scale, so uses it for a loop of 50,000 or 1,000,000 and runs into issues

Comment: So for the same reason I do not advocate the use of loops, I don't advocate the use of recursive CTEs except for when dealing with Hierarchical data. The solution using `spt_values` also does not scale in it's current form (as you have pointed out in your answer). So while I can't answer on behalf of @gvee, the reason I posted the answer after you had posted yours is that although the performance difference between our answers may be minimal, the techniques I have used are better practise as shown in tests linked to in the answer.

Comment: I agree, the recursive solution is kind of slow, just tested. Thank you for clarifying this. I was refering to the second part of the query. I didn't find it necessary to create my own tally, but it seems more than fast enough

Answer (score 2):

This solution it is limited to 2048 days, but can be expanded with a different tally:

```
SELECT cast(dateadd(day, -number, @startdate) as date) date
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE 
  type = 'P' 
  AND dateadd(day, -number, @StartDate) >= @EndDate
  AND @BreakDate NOT BETWEEN dateadd(day, 1 - number, @StartDate) AND @startdate
```

Answer (score 1):

Homework? ;)

```
DECLARE @dateStart SMALLDATETIME = '20150315'
DECLARE @dateEnd SMALLDATETIME = '20150305'
DECLARE @dateBreak SMALLDATETIME = '20150310'

WHILE (@dateStart>@dateEnd)
    BEGIN
        print @dateStart;
        IF (@dateStart=@dateBreak) BREAK
        SET @dateStart-=1
    END
```